# Is there a single word to express the idea of "remove from existence"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing a simple application which will remove any trace that I was ever at a PC. (Not for nefarious reasons before anyone asks - I do a lot of temporary work at client sites and when  I leave, I want an easy way of uninstalling all my applications and software licenses)

Coding is the easy part but what to call it... that has me stumped. Don't laugh, names are important!

I could just go with something boring like "AppCleaner" but I was hoping to find something a little more interesting. It's probably getting into the realms of philosophy but are there any words (in any language) to express the concept of "remove from existence"?

**edit** the original wording was "never existed" but, as pointed out in the comment, that's not quite the same thing as removing from existence which is what I'm actually after.

Comment: I was originally going for never existed but changed the theme to "removed from existence" because it fits my goal better. I'll edit the question

Comment: As I said, I was looking for something more interesting. I could use "Application Remover", which describes perfectly what the thing is doing but that's just boring!

Comment: You could turn the files into [unfiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Newspeak_words#Unperson)

Comment: While multiple words, _Back to the Future_ and all that it entails may lead you down the path to focusing on going back in time versus  _remove from existence_ which is focused on removing what has already existed. Starting Point, Alpha, etc...could be references to going back in time.

Comment: Wow. This question closed between the time I completed my answer and the time I finished logging in. Anyway, my answer is this: What about `nullify`?

    transitive verb
    1 : to make null; especially : to make legally null and void
    2 : to make of no value or consequence

This is especially fitting (in my opinion) as you're writing a **computer program**, where  "null" is (usually) an especially important reserved code word.

Comment: Looks like the question was closed by the powers that be between me leaving the office and getting home. Thanks all for the great suggestions but sadly I can only pick one so the answer goes to "**Expunge**", which is a great word that just isn't used enough!

Comment: '... in any language' takes this off-topic here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**expunge**

> erase or remove completely (something unwanted or unpleasant) : *the communists had expunged references to the Hitler-Stalin pact.*

Comment: and the logo would be of a sponge with an X on it...

Comment: The word "expunge" is used in law to refer to destroying all legal record of a crime, usually because the crime was committed when the person was under 18 and the idea is that a person shouldn't have a criminal record for his whole life because of one irresponsible thing he did when he was a teenager.

Comment: And this new app will be called "Expunge Bob".

Answer (score 15):

'Obliterate' could be the word you are looking for. But I don't know if you think its suitable for the name of an app..!! 
'Annul' also means the same to some extent. You could modify these words to come up with a suitable name.

Comment: First word that came to my thoughts.

Answer (score 14):

**Annihilate**

> (v. t.)  To reduce to nothing or nonexistence; to destroy the
>   existence of; to cause to cease to be.
>
> (v. t.)  To destroy the form or peculiar distinctive properties of, so
>   that the specific thing no longer exists; as, to annihilate a forest
>   by cutting down the trees.

Answer (score 6):

[Purge](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/purge?show=0&t=1322500151)

> 1. to rid of whatever is impure or undesirable; cleanse; purify.
> 2. to rid, clear, or free (usually followed by of  or from ): to purge a political party of disloyal members.
> 3. to clear of imputed guilt or ritual uncleanliness.
> 4. to clear away or wipe out legally (an offense, accusation, etc.) by atonement or other suitable action.
> 5. to remove by cleansing or purifying (often followed by away, off,  or out ).

Answer (score 3):

*Eradicate* (literally to remove even the roots)?

Or (less accurate but more fun) *pulverise*, to reduce to dust.

Answer (score 3):

My favorite from below: 'Eliminar'

> English:
>   expunge, eradicate, sanitize, obliterate, delete, erase
>   Latin:
>   expunge, delere, sanitize, delere, delete, deleo
>   French:
>   expurger, éradiquer, désinfecter, effacer, supprimer, effacer
>   German:
>   expunge, zu beseitigen, desinfizieren, auslöschen, löschen, löschen
>   Spanish:
>   borrar, eliminar, desinfectar, borrar, eliminar, borrar

Comment: "Eliminar" would be perfect if you need your app to seem like it was written by Tolkienian elves.

Answer (score 1):

My background in the cleaning chemical business brings to mind *sanitize*, *disinfect*, and *sterilize*, the three terms which have regulatory definitions. **Sanitize** is probably the best because its connotation is more "clean" and less "bug free" than the others.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a commodity software product, I suggest you limit yourself to terms which are widely used and understood. I suggest a writing metaphor, because that will be instantly familiar. In that context, the notion of removing from existence or the concept of something which is removed so perfectly that it is as if it had never existed leads to solutions such as **undo**, **erase**, and **white out**.

Answer (score 0):

"poof" would be a less clinical alternative to the proposed answers.

You simple poof yourself (or your footprints) out of existence.

Comment: High risk of offense!

Comment: @e100, Probably less so in the USA (where Slothsberry is located).

Comment: What's the risk of offence here?

Comment: @AlexBrault "Poof" is an insulting word for a gay man in UK slang.

Comment: I assumed the application would be available to UK English markets.

Answer (score 0):

I think that eradicate or expunge is the correct verb; so Trace Eradicator or Trace Expunger.